# SQuirreL SQL Client add aliases error

Tags: apache-phoenix, squirrel-sql

When I am add alias in SQuirreL SQL Client to connect hbase using phoenix,this is the exception log:

```
Unexpected Error occurred attempting to open an SQL connection.
```

This is the detail:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:206)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.awaitConnection(OpenConnectionCommand.java:132)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$100(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$2.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:115)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:171)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.access$000(OpenConnectionCommand.java:45)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand$1.run(OpenConnectionCommand.java:104)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2579)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2294)
    at org.apache.phoenix.util.PhoenixContextExecutor.call(PhoenixContextExecutor.java:76)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.init(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2294)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.getConnectionQueryServices(PhoenixDriver.java:232)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.createConnection(PhoenixEmbeddedDriver.java:147)
    at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver.connect(PhoenixDriver.java:202)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.fw.sql.SQLDriverManager.getConnection(SQLDriverManager.java:133)
    at net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.mainframe.action.OpenConnectionCommand.executeConnect(OpenConnectionCommand.java:167)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:208)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.call(ClientScanner.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.nextScanner(ClientScanner.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.initializeScannerInConstruction(ClientScanner.java:160)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ClientScanner.<init>(ClientScanner.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getScanner(HTable.java:802)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.fullScan(MetaTableAccessor.java:602)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MetaTableAccessor.tableExists(MetaTableAccessor.java:366)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.tableExists(HBaseAdmin.java:396)
    at org.apache.phoenix.query.ConnectionQueryServicesImpl$13.call(ConnectionQueryServicesImpl.java:2331)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.ZooKeeperWatcher.getMetaReplicaNodes(ZooKeeperWatcher.java:489)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.zookeeper.MetaTableLocator.blockUntilAvailable(MetaTableLocator.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZooKeeperRegistry.getMetaRegionLocation(ZooKeeperRegistry.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateMeta(ConnectionManager.java:1211)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(ConnectionManager.java:1178)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.getRegionLocations(RpcRetryingCallerWithReadReplicas.java:305)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:156)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
    ... 24 more
```

This is my configuration:

[image]

Where is going wrong,am i missing some jar file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string is not correct,change to:

```
jdbc:phoenix:192.168.24.226,192.168.24.195:2181:/hbase-unsecure
```

192.168.24.195 is the namenode contains zookeeper,192.168.24.226 is the datanode.